# How to activate middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

Do I have to activate it elsewhere or can you help me? When I run the project, it goes straight to the controller and middleware does not run.

This is my middleware.

```cs
public class AuthenticationMiddleWare
{
    private RequestDelegate nextDelegate;
        
    public AuthenticationMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration config)
    {
        nextDelegate = next;
    }
        
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            // somecode
            await nextDelegate.Invoke(httpContext);
        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For .NET Core, .NET 5 with Startup.cs**

Make sure you have registered your middleware in `Configure` method in Startup class.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleWare>();
    }
}
```

**Reference:** [The Configure method - App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-configure-method)

---

**For .NET 6 and above without Startup.cs**

1. Write an extension method for middleware.

```cs
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuthenticationMiddleware(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleWare>();
    }
}
```

2. Register `AuthenticationMiddleWare` with the extension method in Program.cs.

```cs
/* Import namespace of MiddlewareExtensions.cs */

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

...


app.UseAuthenticationMiddleware(); // Register middleware, order of sequence matter

...

app.Run();
```

**Reference:** [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/8017690/yong-shun